# Acces variable in Ajax function and change JSON path

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, variables

I'm trying to make a folder system. All the folders and files are stored in a json file.

**What I want to achieve:**
When a user clicks on a folder, it should open the content in that folder. There could be another folder in that folder, so the user must be able to open that one too.

To achieve this I want to store the path of the folders the user is navigating in into the variable crum. Every time the path changes it should recall the function "callRoot" to open the new path.

**So what's going wrong with this code:**
When I recall the callRoot function it alerts the right (new) path. But after the succes it alerts [object object]. I'm completely new to AJAX, I'm having a hard time passing variables through functions.

I hope this explains my situation better.

```
var crum = "root";

$(document).on('click', '.folder', function(){  
    var folderName = $(this).attr('id');
    crum = crum + '.' + folderName;
    callRoot(crum);
});

function callRoot(crum){
    alert(crum);
    var crum = crum;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'installation/directory.json',
            data: {
            get_param: 'value'
            },dataType: 'json',
            success: function(crum){

                alert(crum);
                root = eval(crum);


                $.each(root, function(index, element){
                    if (isNaN(index)) {
                        $("#sideFolderContainer").append("<li class='folder' id=" + index + ">" + index + "</li>");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#sideFolderContainer").append("<li>" + element + "</li>");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}

callRoot(crum);
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little better? Or maybe provide some context for the UI of this program. This code doesn't really make much sense considering you are making references to variables that are not in scope.

Comment: Also, put the content of directory.json.